# How to send a task with schedule to celery while worker is running?

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I've problem to creating and adding beat schedule task to the celery worker and running that when the celery worker is currently running

well this is my code

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery('proj2')
app.config_from_object('proj2.celeryconfig')


@app.task
def hello() -> None:
    print(f'Hello')


app.add_periodic_task(10.0, hello)
```

so when i am running the celery

```
$ celery -A proj2 worker --beat -E
```

this works very well and the task will run every 10 seconds

***But***

I need to create a task with schedule and sending that to the worker to run it automatically

**Imagine** i have run the worker celery and every things is ok
well i go to the python shell and do following code

```bash
>>> from proj2.celery import app
>>>
>>> app.conf.beat_schedule = {
...    'hello-every-5': {
...        'tasks': 'proj2.tasks.bye' # i have a task called bye in tasks module
...        'schedule': 5.0,
...    }
...}
>>>
```

it's not working. Also there is no error
but it seems does not send to the worker

p.s: i have also used `add_periodic_task` method. still not working

Comment: I do not think that is possible (I hope I am wrong). You need to restart the beat process in order for Celery to start using the new schedule. Perhaps with custom-made scheduler it could be done...

Comment: oh. one more thing about you opinion! should i restart the worker manually or something else

Comment: Ideally, you run beat separately (as a separate process). If you do not, I suggest you do that in the future so that you can restart beat whenever you need to.

Comment: Well I have done this by django-celery-beat